# Web Page cannot be loaded on git-pages

Tags: github-pages

My web page using framework 7 can be loaded on my local desktop, but is not working on gh-pages

I think, Index.html is loaded correctly but there is some error on there.

I will attach related links about my web page to let you understand easily.

https://hahmmj.github.io/IPP20201_HALFSTACK/

https://github.com/hahmmj/IPP20201_HALFSTACK/tree/gh-pages

Before running it on the local drive, I inserted the following statement, which is recommended on forum web site, due to some errors:

- npm uninstall copy-webpack-plugin
- npm install copy-webpack-plugin@6.2.1

Should I add this sentences also in package.json file to publish my web site using github pages?

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "not working"? What have you tried to make it work?

Comment: Are you sure your project structure is correct? I tried running `npm install`, followed by `npm start` and the build errored. I was, however, able to run your project after moving the contents of the  `docs` folder into a manually created `src` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, see my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65762280/web-page-cannot-be-loaded-on-git-pages#comment116271948_65762280) on fixing your directory structure. You can fix that as simply as:

```sh
mv docs src
```

Then run the following commands:

```sh
npm install
npm run build-prod
```

Your page in now ready inside folder `www`.

Now you have to overwrite the contents of your `gh-pages` branch with the files generated inside `www`.

Answer (score 0):

you have messed up with the directory structure of your website . In a ideal case you should be able to see your hosted page on GitHub by entering the URL like this
`https://hahmmj.github.io/IPP20201_HALFSTACK/docs/index.html`